# How to programmatically create a new Emacs frame with a given name?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I need to be able to create frames and to refer to them programmatically.

How can one create a new Emacs frame with a given name, so that he can refer to it later on?

I know how to create new frames, either interactively or programmatically: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Creating-Frames.html

It is possible to display a frame title in different ways: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameTitle but I could not find how to set and refer to a frame name.

A code pointer or a precise search engine search would suffice.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @lawlist Thank you for your reference to `set-frame-name`, it helps clarify the issue. With that and all the help I came up with a proper function that does what I need. I listed it as an answer, if that is all right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to get a frame, given its name. Use function **`get-a-frame`**, in library [`frame-fns.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/frame-fns.el) to do that.

And if you want to get the frame name from a frame, use function `get-frame-name` in the same library.

(See also library [`frame-cmds.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/frame-cmds.el).)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And thank you for all the very nice libraries, truly inspiring.

Comment: Both links are 404.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski: Thx. Corrected (Emacs wiki changed from using http to using https.

Answer (score 1):

See `select-frame-set-input-focus` at http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-Focus.html. For example, try

```
(select-frame-set-input-focus (second (frame-list)))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Emacs assign an internal code when creating a new frame. In my case, the secon one was `#<frame *scratch* 0x112ec2440>`. So, `(frame-list)` was returning `(#<frame *scratch* 0x112ec2440> #<frame *scratch* 0x105013b98>)`. Then, your code snippet will allow me to switch to the second frame in that list. I guess one would use the last element of that list? Would that be the most recent frame?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all for the links and the code. I have learned a lot!

After studying those pages, it seems that Emacs does not allow to assign a custom ID to a new frame.

So, in order to uniquely reference a newly created frame, one needs to catch the ID assigned by Emacs at creation time.

I can now better express what I was looking for with a function like this:

```
(defun my/frame-create (&optional title)
  "Create a new frame returning its internal id,
   optionally setting TITLE as title"
  (interactive "sNew frame name: ")
  (progn
    (setq my/frame-id (make-frame-command))
    (set-frame-name title))
  my/frame-id)
```

This function creates a new frame, and returns its ID, so that that frame can be called at any time.

I would be grateful for any comments to write this or similar function with proper elisp idiom.

Thank you once again to all for the advice.

Comment: Does `(selected-frame)` return what you're looking for?:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-Focus.html  However, that value is not stored as part of the `(frame-parameters)`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Parameter-Access.html#Parameter-Access

Comment: Yes, `(selected-frame)` returns the frame's ID. That could be another way of doing it, calling `selected-frame` right after `make-frame-command`. Thank you.